# How to auto scale on Kubernetes (GKE) with a pod that runs one per node and uses all available resources?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I think I have a pretty simple scenario:  I need to auto-scale on Google Kubernetes Engine with a pod that runs one per node and uses all available remaining resources on the node.

"Remaining" resources means that there are certain basic pod services running on each node such logging and metrics, which need their requested resources. But everything left should go to this particular pod, which is in fact the main web service for my cluster.

Also, these remaining resources should be available when the pod's container starts up, rather than through vertical autoscaling with pod restarts. The reason is that the container has certain constraints that make restarts sort of expensive: heavy disk caching, and issues with licensing of some 3rd party software I use. So although certainly the container/pod is restartable, I'd like to avoid except for rolling updates.

The cluster should scale nodes when CPU utilization gets too high (say, 70%). And I don't mean requested CPU utilization of a node's pods, but rather the actual utilization, which is mainly determined by the web service's load.

How should I configure the cluster for this scenario? I've seen there's cluster auto scaling, vertical pod autoscaling, and horizontal pod autoscaling. There's also Deployment vs DaemonSet, although it does not seem that DaemonSet is designed for pods that need to scale. So I think Deployment may be necessary, but in a way that limits one web service pod per node (pod anti affinity??).

How do I put all this together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a Deployment with a resource request that equals a single node's allocatable resources (i.e., total resources minus auxiliary services as you mentioned). Then configure Horizontal Pod Autoscaling to scale up your deployment when CPU request utilization goes above 70%; this should do the trick as in this case request utilization rate is essentially the same as total node resource utilization rate, right? However if you do want to base scaling on actual node CPU utilization, there's always [scaling by external metrics](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/external-metrics-autoscaling).

Technically the Deployment's resource request doesn't have to exactly equal remaining resources; rather it's enough for the request to be large enough to prevent two pods being ran on the same node. As long as that's the case and there's no resource limits, the pod ends up consuming all the available node resources.

Finally configure cluster autoscaling on your GKE node pool and we should be good to go. Vertical Pod Autoscaling doesn't really come into play here as pod resource request stays constant, and DaemonSets aren't applicable as they're not scalable via HPA as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks very much! That seems to work. Here's a couple of extra notes in case anyone has the same scenario:  (1) The external metric for CPU utilization can be configured under HorizontalPodAutoscaler using the metric name "kubernetes.io|node|cpu|allocatable_utilization with matchLabels for "resource.labels.project_id" and "resource.labels.cluster_name".  (2) Under deployment resource requests, it's important to keep in mind that GKE reserves a portion of the resources that can not be requested:  https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#node_allocatable

Comment: Also as an additional safeguard, there's the [`default-max-pods-per-node`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/flexible-pod-cidr#configuring_maximum_pods_per_node) option that can be used to configure clusters or node pools.

Comment: I just noticed an issue when I update the version of the web service container image. The cluster scaled up in order to deploy the new pod version (rolling update with old versions still running), then it removed the old pod version, and then it began to scale down the cluster to fit just the new pod version. But it got stuck in an uneven distribution of nodes across zones. The GKE docs so mention that scale down doesn't balance, but still it should be able to remove another node.

Comment: True, although they [`plan to take balancing into account in scale-down in the future`](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#im-running-cluster-with-nodes-in-multiple-zones-for-ha-purposes-is-that-supported-by-cluster-autoscaler). Can't see any way around it, other than tweaking minimum/maximum node pool sizes but that can of course hinder elasticity. Eventually when your cluster scales up it should balance itself across regions, right?

Comment: Yeah, I just pushed a new deployment with updated container image, and it first scaled-up during the rolling update, then scaled back down to an even distribution with the expected number of nodes. So I guess it gets it right every other update, haha.